# PHP echo css class?

Tags: php, css

I've got php structure and want embed my div in php. Must write css with echo class but i don't know how do it.

My div:

```
<div class="mydiv">
                <img src="catalog/view/theme/default/img/mypng.png" alt="">
            </div>
```

How can fix it?

Comment: erm, what do you mean by echoing CSS class?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how doing it but i want learn this. Why - rep?

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to know. Please try to explain your problem better.

Comment: @Nerd-Herd i want like this: echo "<p>{$product['name']}</p>{$product['price']}<br></div>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, is this what you're talking about?

```
echo '
    <div class="mydiv">
        <img src="catalog/view/theme/default/img/mypng.png" alt="">
    </div>';
```

Comment: Yes, very very thank you for learning this trick.

Comment: You're lucky I'm psychic and can read minds :)

Comment: Working for great English and code world, really trying :)